# I want to see the username of a person in the response JSON of a Login API

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

there I am new to WordPress.

I have created a Login API, using the plugin called **simple jwt login**, but it returns me the response like this.

{

"success": true,

"data": {

```
"jwt": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.MSWyFCyu6D88dj2MhD7MrV9x1-L7MUnFS4WAKyc_ALo"
```

}
}

**--> But I am looking for the response like this:**

{

"success": true,

"data": {

```
"jwt": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.MSWyFCyu6D88dj2MhD7MrV9x1-L7MUnFS4WAKyc_ALo",
"oldUserId": null,
"displayName": "Abduallah test",
"roles": [
    "customer"
],
"expiresIn": 1652854151
```

}

How can I make changes to the plugin code to achieve the above response??

I appreciate your efforts and support in advance.
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Try this plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/

Comment: Did u try to decode the jwt in response from the api?

Comment: @Weber, Yes I decoded the response of JWT,  this is the response I got: {
 alg: "RS256",
 kid: "lhoOl3GbVXmu7J55YoHK2O9DIeKsizUWaXfpyiDjXT8"
}.
{
 userId: "75700",
 oldUserId: null,
 sessionId: "b1593d04-7603-4188-b5b9-2e7c8be93a32",
 iss: "app@secure.nrtcfresh.com",
 sub: "app@secure.nrtcfresh.com",
 exp: 1668242757,
 kind: "auth-token",
 roles: [
  "customer"
 ],
 cocart_key: {
  c_key: "ck_ec1c7b1ae2be15c8552d9ca784e48aaae61c5e87",
  c_secret: "cs_07bf21711010dc4683eca47a4e5bcf805857de2e"
 }
}.
[signature]

Comment: @MohammedAliyaan pleasure brother :)

Comment: @MohammedAliyaan edit the code of the plugin in output search for string who encode the exit parameter and comment the encode

Comment: @Weber Thanks brother for your support. I'll do it.